Coq: when to give a context variable of imported package as argument
I'm a beginner in Coq.
When I run the following code
From Coq Require Import Relations.Relation_Definitions.
From Coq Require Import Classes.RelationClasses.

Context {A : Type}.
Context {Virer: relation A}.

Print relation.

Print complement.

Definition virer := relation A.
Print virer.

Definition virer2 := complement Virer.
Print virer2.

Definition virer3 := complement A.

I get the following messages:
relation = fun A : Type => A -> A -> Prop
     : Type -> Type

Arguments relation A%type_scope

complement = fun (A : Type) (R : relation A) (x y : A) => R x y -> False
     : forall A : Type, relation A -> relation A

Arguments complement {A}%type_scope R _ _

virer = relation A
     : Type

virer2 = complement Virer
     : relation A

The term "A" has type "Type" while it is expected to have type
 "relation ?A".

I don't understand why, as (A : Type) appears as the first argument for both relation and complement, virer gets defined without error, while virer2 and virer3 seem to show that complement requires (only) the argument (R : relation A) to be given.

In Arguments complement {A}%type_scope R _ _, the curly braces tell you that A is an implicit argument of complement, so the first argument that you explicitly give to complement is the relation R. Note that A can be inferred from the type of R, so it makes sense to leave A implicit.

OK I think I get it. But then we can't with a definition of involution express that complement is involutive, can we?

Yes, but with @ apparently

Yes, @ident deactivates the implicit arguments of ident. You can also pass implicit arguments by names, as follows: complement (A := nat) le.
